# Mysql SELECT look for duplicates "except" the current one

Tags: php, mysql

I have some code right now that looks to see if a key has been used.  the only issue is that right now it finds its self if the entry is being modified. What would be a good way to look for duplicates "except" the current one?  I do have an unique id called "id".  I have a list of Keys for people. Each key is for only one person. Sometimes when people at the office take a key from a bank of keys we have. Then forget to delete the key from the bank of keys we have. Then when the next person takes a key they take the last one that was used. We end up selling the game key to different people. That is why I need to check for duplicates in the viprek, but not trigger the "This key is already in use" screen if they are changing the entry with that key in it.

init.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect(localhost, root, passwordexmaple);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("arkamanc_vipre", $con);
?>
```

modify.php

http://pastebin.com/5shCfKWu

Edit.php

http://pastebin.com/CVjaS8Lh

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: If not `This`, then duplicate of what?

Comment: How are you identifying "the current one?"

Comment: Do you know the unique ID of the entry being modified? If so, then check `AND id != $id`.

Comment: Yes I know the unique ID.

Comment: please give an example of what you mean by "except the current one".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c2.id FROM client AS c1, client AS c2
  WHERE c1.viprek = c2.viprek
  AND c1.viprek != :viprek
  AND c1.id < c2.id
```

The above query will return the `id` of all entries of table `client` which are a duplicate of another entry on the `viprek` column, except for the one with value held in `$_POST`. You should get the newer duplicates only (id rank-wise).

This is the change you should do in order to get the expected behaviour in your script:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM client AS c1, client AS c2 WHERE c1.viprek = c2.viprek AND c1.viprek!=".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[viprek])." AND c1.id < c2.id";
```

If what you want is the entries containing a specific values for the `viprek` column and `id` other than a specific one, here's the query.

```
SELECT id FROM client
   WHERE id != :id 
   AND viprek = :viprek
```

You can simply modify your `$query` variable to include this query, as it has been already shown above.

However, you are strongly encouraged to use PDO to do all your DB queries. I suggest you learn how to do it or hire someone to take care of it. Here's a [tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) for you to do the transition to PDO.

I'm not sure if this is what you want though.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but how exactly should I structure the code into my code?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking how you should write the query within your PHP code?

Comment: Yes, sorry I am not a programmer I just needed a database to track some keys at work.  So I have blindly walked through this processes.

Comment: sure. Without a better view of the codebase, I don't think I can help you. You need to put the information in your comment in the question, describe what is in the init script (be sure to remove any sensitive information).

Comment: or you could describe the database structure, so that people understand how things are supposed to work. But remember that this is not a site for getting your code done by other people. It's about developers helping other developers when they are stuck doing something.